# Using Outlook Redemption with VB

Tags: vb.net, outlook-redemption, pst

Ok so here is what I am trying to do: I need to access a bunch of PSTs on my computer, cycle through each email and make a modification to a text tag in the email then finish up with the same PST + modifications. I have found out that I need to use Outlook Redemption with Visual Basic (2010) but I have never used either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an RDOSession object.
2. Call RDOSession.LogonPstStore.
3. Enumerate RDOFolders collection under PSTStore.IPMRootFolder.
4. Recursively enumerate RDOFolders collection of each folder if desired.
5. Check the RDPFolder.DefaultMessageClass to make sure it contains the type of item you're looking for.
6. Enumerate the items in the folder.